# Measurement of high voltage with low voltage circuit

Tags: voltage-measurement, instrumentation-amplifier, precision

Is it possible to make a high-impedance, precision measurement of a 10V DC signal (dynamic range requirement is only ±1V with a DC-1kHz BW) using amplifiers and an Sigma-Delta ADC supplied only by +3.3V (or +5V)?

I can't use an instrumentation amplifier without at least a +12V/-2V supply. A voltage divider would be a trade-off between input impedance and Johnson noise.

Is there another way to do this that I am missing? A way to subtract the 10V bias without needing higher voltages in my circuit?

Comment: Measurement with what? Is this going into an ADC or an analog circuit?

Comment: A voltage divider followed by an opamp buffer? What specifically do you need the high impedance for?

Comment: Measurement is with an ADC. There is a variable contact resistance in the system so I do not want my meter to draw any current. Presently I am using an INA129 with +/-15V supplies from a DC-DC converter.

Comment: You need precision? Or accuracy? Actually, there are many other specs that would be nice to know about and might affect (eliminate) ideas. How often will the measurement be made? (Has to do with loading, at the very least. So less often is better if you want not to "draw any current.") Will you calibrate it for accuracy? If so, how? How much drift over time (months or longer?) and over ambient temperature variation range can you accept?

Comment: Accuracy is important but I don't yet have a specification for temp sensitivity and long term drift. Will be calibrated in the lab and against an on-board voltage reference. For precision I need 50µV resolution over the 2V dynamic range centered at the DC offset level with up to 100Hz BW. We can assume for now that the measurement is continuous but contact resistance to the DUT can drift.

Comment: Perhaps the voltage divider is not as bad as I expected. I still get 0.1% accuracy when adding a 150kΩ divider load and the noise contribution is negligible since the 30k+120k divider only presents a 24k source impedance to the amplifier. Johnson noise at room temp is only 20nV/√Hz so I can actually use an even bigger divider.

Comment: I think that you might be looking at a null-meter kind of setup. i.e. you have a 10V known source and measure the difference. 

You only need the range of the expected maximum difference (±1V in your case). Or you can ever have a reference adjustable from 9 to 11V. This is the "classic" way of making precise measurements in metrology.

Comment: Watch out for the sampling surge currents. 10pf at 100,000 at 10 volts will appear as (10pF * 10v = 100picoCoulomb ) * 100,000Hz or 1e-10 Coul * 10^+5 Hz = 1e-5 amperes. That, 10uA, times 24Kohm, causes 0.24 volts error.

Comment: @Undertalk The null-meter is precisely what I am doing. After the 5x divider brings the DC offset on scale I use a DAC to null out remaining 2V. Hence my other question posted yesterday.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Still trying to wrap my head around the sampling surge current. I think you are saying that my GΩ op-amp input is not as high as I think at high frequencies and the displacement current causes an offset error. I think you must be getting the 100kHz signal from my lock-in amplifier question; this is actually a different circuit and the signal is <1kHz.

Comment: You can boost the 3.3V up to 12V at a fewmA and make a diff-amp from rail-to-rail op-amps. Power the diff amp with 12V. The diff amp can measure voltage difference between the 10V and some other precision reference (like an 8V reference) which you would have to derive from 12V.